# API response send issue in mongoDb.

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, response

I'm using mongodb for make backend API. And I have used `bluebird` to use promise.

```
return new promise((resolve, reject) => {

    db.collection('employee').find({
        email: data.email
    }).toArray().then((checkEmail) => {
        if (checkEmail.length > 0) {                
            res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Employee already exist.' });
            // I want to stop my node hear. 
            // I have tried return false , but not works.
        }
    }).then(() => {
        // Add employee details into collection as a new employee. 
        return db.collection('employee').insert({
            //...
        })
    }).then((employee) => {
         // Other stuff
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Something went wrong.' });
    });;
}
```

As you can see if `checkEmail > 0` , then I have send response which I got proper in postman. But still my node is execute next code.

So how could I stop next execution when I send res back.

I have already send res to client then also it execute next code  and in other part I have also send success/error res. That's why I got this error.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I have tried to use `return` , `return false`. But it's still execute my next code.

Comment: Returning from then doesn't stop the promise chain (it passes the returned value to the next then in the chain). You could throw your own error and handle it in the catch differently than you handle the general error.   
e: Also I suggest tagging the question with Promise and javascript as it's not exactly mongodb related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new promise in your return statement is not needed, you can return the chain itself if you need your method to produce a promise.
Returning from `then` in promise chain does not stop the chain, it just passes the returned value as an argument to the next `then`. One way to bypass it is to throw your own custom error and handle it approprietly in the `catch`. Something like this should work:

```
return db
  .collection("employee")
  .find({email: data.email})
  .toArray()
  .then(checkEmail => {
    if (checkEmail.length > 0) {
      let err = new Error("Employee already exists.");
      err.code = "EMPLOYEE_ALREADY_EXISTS";
      throw err;
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    // Add employee details into collection as a new employee.
    return db.collection("employee").insert({
      //...
    });
  })
  .then(employee => {
    // Other stuff
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code && error.code === "EMPLOYEE_ALREADY_EXISTS") {
      res.send({ status: 0, message: "Employee already exists." });
    } else {
      console.log(error);
      res.send({ status: 0, message: "Something went wrong." });
    }
  });
```

edit: Just to make it clear again the employee in the third `then` will be whatever you return from the previous `then`, i.e. whatever `db.collection("employee").insert({...})` returns.

Answer (score 0):

you can just branch your promise like

```
db.collection('employee')
.find({
    email: data.email
 })
.toArray()
.then((checkEmail) => {
   if (checkEmail.length > 0) {                
     return res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Employee already exist.'});
   }
   else
   {
     return db.collection('employee').insert({
        //...
        })
        .then((employee) => {
           // Other stuff})
        })
   }
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Something went wrong.' });
});
```

Or you can just branch your promise by binding it with different onSuccess calls.
One branch will decide whether to send a message or not. Since the promises are chained the only way is to pass the state throughout the promise chain like in the other branch.

```
let exists = db.collection('employee')
    .find({
        email: data.email
     })
    .toArray()

 exists.then((checkEmail)=>{
    if(checkEmail.length > 0){
       return res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Employee already exist.'});
       //ends the excution here
    }
 })
 exists.then((checkEmail)=>{
      return checkEmail.length === 0;
   }
 })
 .then((createUser) => {
   if(createUser){
     return db.collection('employee').insert({
        //...
    })
    else
     return createUser
   }
 })
 .then((createUser)=> {
   if(createUser) {
     // Other stuff
   }
 })
 .catch((err)=>{
    console.log(error)
    res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Something went wrong.' });
 })
```

Comment: Isn't nesting the promises instead of chaining them considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: Its subjective on the use case but if its over used then yes is a bad practice. 
Let me edit my solution

Comment: @VáclavPruner Thanks for your reply. I have tried `return res.send({ status: 0, message: 'Employee already exist.'});` but it's not works for me.